# how to convert a jar to dll, the jar depending on multi jars

Tags: dll, jar, ikvm

Hi i try to use ikvmc (http://www.ikvm.net/) to conver a jar to a dll

the jar is :

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/284185/dartapi.jar

but that jar depends on multi jars as well,

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/284185/lib.zip

what command should i use to convert that jar to a dll???

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can compile it in one step:

```
ikvmc { file1.jar }  { file2.jar } ...
```

or you need to compile it in the order of dependency if there is a hierarchy and no circle dependency.

See the [IKVM Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=ClassLoader) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You compile the dependent jar into a dll first and then reference it when you compile the main jar.

Something like:

```
ikvmc -target:library depend.jar
ikvmc -target:library -resource:depend.dll dartapi.jar
```

See:
[IKVM docs](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html)