# How do I use IKVMC to convert a specific JAR file to DLL when the jar file has various outgoing dependencies?

Tags: java, dll, jar, ibm-mq, ikvm

I'm working with Websphere MQ. And I need to convert a specific JAR file to a DLL. [Here](http://goo.gl/zC1NdM) is the collection of JARS from the WMQ Client. [Here](http://goo.gl/k9mDkw) is the JAR Analyzer File for the collection listing the various incoming and outgoing dependencies.

The File I want to convert is `com.ibm.mq.jar` which has the following outgoing dependencies -

```
 com.ibm.mq.commonservice.jar
 com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
 com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
```

**The problem is I don't know what command to pass in the command prompt to convert the jar without losing any of the classes.**

Basically, I need to get access to MQMessage and MQMD which are part of `com.ibm.mq.jar` but when I convert it by itself, those specific classes doesn't get imported.

I took a look at [another similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446113/how-to-convert-a-jar-to-dll-the-jar-depending-on-multi-jars) but the main difference is that the dependencies are circular.

For example, `com.ibm.mq.headers.jar` depends on `com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar` and vice-versa.

Comment: What's your requirement to do conversion of the JAR files please? There are .net clients to MQ.

Comment: I need to connect to MQ without having the client installed. Don't ask me why. My bosses asked me to do it. I did. Now they want features.

Comment: I appreciate the client installation puts a lot of material on the machine; however you going to need some client libraries .net or JARs (converted or not) copied on the machine where the program is running.

Keep in mind that IBM service won't extend to any converted JARs.

Comment: @Calanais I know that. Currently I can send a message and receive a reply from my MQ server. But I need to specify the queue to which the Server should reply to. To do that, I need to import `com.ibm.mq.jar`. Hence, asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you will not read the MQ link that I gave.

(1) Create a pure '.NET managed' MQ application

```
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
Hashtable qMgrProp = new Hashtable();
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);  /* very important */
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "10.10.10.10");
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "TEST.CHL");
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
qMgrProp.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "myUserID");

try
{
   MQQueueManager _qMgr = new MQQueueManager("MQA1", qMgrProp);

   MQQueue queue = _qMgr.AccessQueue("TEST.Q", openOptions, null, null, null);

   /* Do whatever you want to do */

   queue.Close();
   _qMgr.Disconnect();
}
catch (MQException mqex)
{
   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQTest01 cc=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : rc=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
}
```

(2) Compile it.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /nologo /t:exe /r:System.dll /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\amqmdnet.dll" /out:bin\Release\Test.exe Test.cs  Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
```

(3) Create "Test.config" file (to go with Test.exe) where Test.exe is stored

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NMQ_MQ_LIB" value="managed"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

(4) Copy 3 files to your target PC: Test.exe, Test.config and amqmdnet.dll and then run it.  You may need to update the PATH environment variable to point to the directory that amqmdnet.dll resides in. This is generally not needed but sometimes Windows get picky.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea about .NET Managed applications prior to your post.

Comment: That's why I gave you the link.

Answer (score 0):

Talk about making your life more difficult than it needs to be.  Make your application a '.NET managed' application then all you need is the MQ dll called amqmdnet.dll (supplied by IBM and it contains everything you need).

Hence, you can run your .NET application without a full install of MQ.  Of course, deploying the amqmdnet.dll file with your application is not supported by IBM but neither is the complicated setup you are trying to do.

Comment: amqmdnet.dll doesn't work without the MQ client installed. Your second para makes no sense to me. What are you trying to say there?

Comment: Yes, it does. Please read the manual: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029450_.htm

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, amqmdnet.dll doesn't work without the MQ client installed. If you know a way to make it work, please let me know. I don't care if it is unsupported.

Comment: OMG. Did you even bother to read the link I gave you?  If you make your MQ application a pure '.NET managed' application then yes it will work.